# Get imageView color and set complementary color

Tags: android, colors, background-image

I make Viewpager and there is only ImageView.

that images from server. So it can be bright or dark.

and there is Layout for notice current page / totalPage like this.

[image]

Now I want to make if Image is bright, notice layout make dark.

and if Image is dark, notice layout make bright.

So. **My Question is**

1. How can I know current image is bright or dark?
2. And How I can make `complementary color` from image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Support Library r21 and above includes the Palette class, which lets you extract prominent colors from an image. To extract these colors, pass a Bitmap object to the Palette.generate() static method in the background thread where you load your images. If you can't use that thread, call the Palette.generateAsync() method and provide a listener instead.

To use the Palette class in your project, add the following Gradle dependency to your app's module:

```
implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:$version'
```

To get the color from image:

```
    Palette.generateAsync(bitmap, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
        public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
            // Do something with colors...
        }
});
```

The palette library attempts to extract the following six color profiles:

Light Vibrant,
Vibrant,
Dark Vibrant,
Light Muted,
Muted and
Dark Muted.

Finding complementary color is very simple in RGB model. For any given color, for example, red (#FF0000) you need to find the color, which, after being added to red, creates white (0xFFFFFF). Naturally, all you need to do, is subtract red from white and get cyan (0xFFFFFF - 0xFF0000 = 0x00FFFF).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will do that!